# Conversion from ZYX Euler to XYZ Euler and to Quaternion

Tags: matrix, vector, 3d, quaternions, euler-angles

I gathered some data from BVH animations, and they are represented in the **ZXY** order **(Right-handed, Y axis world up vector)**.

And I need to transform this into:

- XYZ Euler
- ZYX Euler
- Quaternion

How would I do this conversion? I tried googling about it but I cannot find any pseudo-code for it, only math explanations which are not that straight forward for me to understand.

Comment: Try code from Graphic Gems 
https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gemsiv/euler_angle/EulerAngles.c

Answer (score 1):

1. **construct transform matrix `m` representing your input euler angle conventions**

   so code that converts BVH input int 4x4 transform matrix. Its simple multiplication by rotation matrices in order ...
2. **convert `m` into desired euler angles convention**

   for that you can use this:

   - [Is there a way to calculate 3D rotation on X and Y axis from a 4x4 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56950130/2521214)

   see the code in [edit1]. You can use it to get euler angles for any convention ... you just use different `cfg`.

   So simply you create cfg for each euler angle convention you got ... and then use it when you want to transform the `m` into it...